# Bad render for included graphic

Tags: graphics, pdftex, includegraphics, rendering

I have the following image which I want to include in my latex writeup

[image]

However, when I include it it render as follows

[image]

The image becomes pixelated and less smooth. I have tried including the image as a pdf and eps with increasing dpi, however no success. I have also played around with scaling the image and setting the width in the includegraphics latex command, which also did not make any change. Any ideas what the problem is and how I could get the image to render properly? Thanks!

EDIT:

I use the following code to render the image.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{image.pdf}
    \centering
\end{figure}
```

and have also tried

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{image.pdf}
    \centering
\end{figure}
```

Here is a link to the original images (pdf and eps): https://we.tl/t-jIABwL2cvC

Comment: First of we probably need to see some code, secondly we probably need to see the image. Thirdly what exactly do you mean by more pixelated and less smooth. I see an image of a bit map at two different scalings.

Comment: do you try it on overleaf.com ? maybe your LaTeX distribution is out of date

Comment: Can we have access to the actual image? And how is that image generated?

Comment: I have attached the original images. Images were generated using matplotlib.